# github actions - npm install is failing with exit code1

Tags: github, npm, github-actions

I am trying to deploy my npm app to azure using github actions. When running npm install its giving an error with exit code 1.v Here is the error its throwing...

```
 npm install, build, and test5s
##[error]Process completed with exit code 1.

> ejs@3.1.3 postinstall /home/runner/work/readbetter/readbetter/node_modules/ejs
> node --harmony ./postinstall.js

npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
added 133 packages from 70 contributors and audited 133 packages in 3.913s

1 package is looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities


> readbetter@1.0.0 test /home/runner/work/readbetter/readbetter
> echo "Error: no test specified" && exit 1

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
Error: no test specified
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! readbetter@1.0.0 test: `echo "Error: no test specified" && exit 1`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the readbetter@1.0.0 test script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/runner/.npm/_logs/2020-06-20T13_55_32_078Z-debug.log
##[error]Process completed with exit code 1.
```

what could be reason?

Here is the repo.
https://github.com/galdiatorocks/readbetter.git

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you look at your `package.json` you literally have `"test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",` in there. So if you try to run the test, it runs into that error.

**To solve it**, you need to either not run the test, or you need to setup proper testing.

And, just running `npm install` works perfectly fine :)

Comment: Thanks! I just removed the npm test & it gets deployed :)

but is it the right thing to do?

Comment: It is in its current state. But, you can of course also add tests, and then set the correct way of starting those tests into package.json. But for now: Yes it was the right thing to do.